# What is incorrect from this All-In-One XML encryption/decryption MSDN sample?

Tags: c#, xml, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I've merged the XML [Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229746.aspx) and [Decryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229919.aspx) from MSDN into the same project below, and am getting the error

> "Unable to retrieve the decryption
>   key".
>   [image]

The strangest thing is that I am able to write the private key before and after the exception, so I'm unsure of what the issue may be.  The merged code is below.

```
   public static void Encrypt(XmlDocument Doc, string ElementToEncrypt, string EncryptionElementID, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
   {
       // Check the arguments.
       if (Doc == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
       if (ElementToEncrypt == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("ElementToEncrypt");
       if (EncryptionElementID == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("EncryptionElementID");
       if (Alg == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
       if (KeyName == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");

       ////////////////////////////////////////////////
       // Find the specified element in the XmlDocument
       // object and create a new XmlElemnt object.
       ////////////////////////////////////////////////
       XmlElement elementToEncrypt = Doc.GetElementsByTagName(ElementToEncrypt)[0] as XmlElement;

       // Throw an XmlException if the element was not found.
       if (elementToEncrypt == null)
       {
           throw new XmlException("The specified element was not found");

       }
       RijndaelManaged sessionKey = null;

       try
       {
           //////////////////////////////////////////////////
           // Create a new instance of the EncryptedXml class
           // and use it to encrypt the XmlElement with the
           // a new random symmetric key.
           //////////////////////////////////////////////////

           // Create a 256 bit Rijndael key.
           sessionKey = new RijndaelManaged();
           sessionKey.KeySize = 256;

           EncryptedXml eXml = new EncryptedXml();

           byte[] encryptedElement = eXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessionKey, false);
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////
           // Construct an EncryptedData object and populate
           // it with the desired encryption information.
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////

           EncryptedData edElement = new EncryptedData();
           edElement.Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl;
           edElement.Id = EncryptionElementID;
           // Create an EncryptionMethod element so that the
           // receiver knows which algorithm to use for decryption.

           edElement.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url);
           // Encrypt the session key and add it to an EncryptedKey element.
           EncryptedKey ek = new EncryptedKey();

           byte[] encryptedKey = EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessionKey.Key, Alg, false);

           ek.CipherData = new CipherData(encryptedKey);

           ek.EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url);

           // Create a new DataReference element
           // for the KeyInfo element.  This optional
           // element specifies which EncryptedData
           // uses this key.  An XML document can have
           // multiple EncryptedData elements that use
           // different keys.
           DataReference dRef = new DataReference();

           // Specify the EncryptedData URI.
           dRef.Uri = "#" + EncryptionElementID;

           // Add the DataReference to the EncryptedKey.
           ek.AddReference(dRef);
           // Add the encrypted key to the
           // EncryptedData object.

           edElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(ek));
           // Set the KeyInfo element to specify the
           // name of the RSA key.

           // Create a new KeyInfo element.
           edElement.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();

           // Create a new KeyInfoName element.
           KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();

           // Specify a name for the key.
           kin.Value = KeyName;

           // Add the KeyInfoName element to the
           // EncryptedKey object.
           ek.KeyInfo.AddClause(kin);
           // Add the encrypted element data to the
           // EncryptedData object.
           edElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encryptedElement;
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           // Replace the element from the original XmlDocument
           // object with the EncryptedData element.
           ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
           EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, edElement, false);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           // re-throw the exception.
           throw e;
       }
       finally
       {
           if (sessionKey != null)
           {
               sessionKey.Clear();
           }

       }

   }
   public static void Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc, RSA Alg, string KeyName)
   {
       // Check the arguments.
       if (Doc == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Doc");
       if (Alg == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Alg");
       if (KeyName == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("KeyName");
       // Create a new EncryptedXml object.
       EncryptedXml exml = new EncryptedXml(Doc);

       // Add a key-name mapping.
       // This method can only decrypt documents
       // that present the specified key name.
       exml.AddKeyNameMapping(KeyName, Alg);

       // Decrypt the element throws Exception:  <--------------
       //
       // Unable to retrieve the decryption key".
       //
        exml.DecryptDocument();

   }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string containerName = "XML_ENC_RSA_KEY";

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Create and persist a key pair
   //  Save the Public portion of the keypair in a string we will use later

        // Create a new CspParameters object to specify
        // a key container.
        CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = containerName;

        // Create a new RSA key and save it in the container.  This key will encrypt
        // a symmetric key, which will then be encryped in the XML document.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
        rsaKey.PersistKeyInCsp = true;
        Console.WriteLine(rsaKey.ToXmlString(false));
        string PublicKeyTest = rsaKey.ToXmlString(false);




  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Encrypt using a new instance of the crypto provider and the public key string



 Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
       var rsaKey2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
       rsaKey2.FromXmlString(PublicKeyTest);
       Console.WriteLine(rsaKey2.ToXmlString(false));
       PublicKeyTest = rsaKey2.ToXmlString(false);


        // Create an XmlDocument object.
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load("test.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

        try
        {
            // Encrypt the "creditcard" element.
            Encrypt(xmlDoc, "creditcard", "EncryptedElement1", rsaKey2, "rsaKey");


            // Save the XML document.
            xmlDoc.Save("testOUT.xml");

            // Display the encrypted XML to the console.
            Console.WriteLine("Encrypted XML:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Clear the RSA key.
            rsaKey2.Clear(); 
        }


        Console.ReadLine();


 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Decrypt the output, using the internal CSP

          xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        // Load an XML file into the XmlDocument object.
        try
        {
            xmlDoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
            xmlDoc.Load("testOUT.xml");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
         cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = containerName;

        // Get the RSA key from the key container.  This key will decrypt
        // a symmetric key that was imbedded in the XML document.
        var rsaKey3 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);
          Console.WriteLine(rsaKey3.ToXmlString(true));
        try
        {

            // Decrypt the elements, throws exception
            Decrypt(xmlDoc, rsaKey3, "rsaKey");

            // Save the XML document.
            xmlDoc.Save("test3.xml");

            // Display the encrypted XML to the console.
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Decrypted XML:");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {

        }


        Console.ReadLine();
```

Full exception (e)

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:
>   Unable to retrieve the decryption key.
>   at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.Xml.EncryptedXml.DecryptDocument()
>   at RemoteKey.Decrypt(XmlDocument Doc,
>   RSA Alg, String KeyName) in
>   C:\Users\me\ClientAgent\Program.cs:line
>   185    at RemoteKey.Main(String[]
>   args) in
>   C:\Users\Me\ClientAgent\Program.cs:line
>   286

Comment: One thing wrong is that you're displaying e.Message. Display the entire `e`.

Comment: That's all? No InnerException?

Comment: Nope... I pasted a screenshot at the top of this post.

Comment: Dear @John means the whole stack trace... That will be more helpful in finding the correct error where it started

Comment: @maker: really, just catch the exception and post the result of ex.ToString().

Comment: @John - I did exactly that.  It is posted to the bottom of the post.  I did that sometime last night.  That text under 'full exception' is the full trace.   That is the trace as shown at the line "exml.DecryptDocument();".  I also noted the source with comments.  Either way, I'm working now, but the MSDN sample is broken AFAIK

Comment: @maker: sorry, it looked truncated.

Comment: Hehe, yea. It's analogous to how I should have truncated my hopes for a MSDN sample working as posted in the official documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Encrypt function is writing XML that does not contain a KeyName element, and so your call to DecryptDocument cannot find the key.

I didn't look any further into why your Encrypt is writing incomplete XML, but you can find another example Encrypt function on MSDN here: [AddKeyNameMapping Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.xml.encryptedxml.addkeynamemapping.aspx).

Replace just your Encrypt function with the function in that MSDN example, changing only the function argument type for Alg from SymmetricAlgorithm to RSA, and remove your third argument "EncryptedElement1" from the call to Encrypt in your existing code, to get it to compile, and it should run to the end of your Decrypt and work.

Once you have that running, you can work backwards looking at the differences in your Encrypt to the one in this example, or, just keep this one if it works for you.

Comment: Works like a charm!  The Encrypt version you found is so much simpler.  I have no idea what the old version is trying to achieve.